# MSSQL Service broker activation "Execute as SELF"

Tags: sql, service-broker

I have a service broker activated stored procdedure that runs fine when executed in management studio. However, when it is activated on the queue, the sql server error log shows the following message:

```
"The activated proc [dbo].[FileUploadAsyncWorker] running on queue
AsyncProcessing.dbo.FileUploadRequestQueue output the following:  'You do not have
permission to use the bulk load statement."
```

I think that the 'offending' statement in FileUploadAsyncWorker is:
    insert into FileContent (filename, content)
    select @filename, content
    from openrowset (bulk...

How do I tell under which user account the stored procedure is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the stored procedure insert the username into a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytemptable (username varchar(max))    
INSERT INTO [MyTempTable] SELECT user
```

My guess is that the SP will run as the SQL Server Service account.

You can also use the SQL Profiler to find out the account which is executing your sp.